# Print $variable value using jQuery is not working properly?

Tags: php, jquery

I have a small interface [Site](https://beta.myimpact.in/TopNews/D.php) (check site interface once) where I am showing  **articles count in yellow box** I am trying to print the value with help of **jQuery** in the column but **value is printing 1 column after** every yellow box

[image] I have tried a lot but nothing works

```html
<div class="news-card NewsList">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 ">
      <div class="news-left pb-0">
        <div class="view-more">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" class="listSimilarNews" href="#collapse<?=$i?>" role="button" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="#collapse<?=$r?>">
            <span id="listSimilarNews"><?php echo (count($nestedarr)); ?></span><br>  
            Articles 
            <i class="accordionarrow icofont-rounded-down"></i> 
          </a>
        </div>
      </div> 
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

```js
$('#listSimilarNews').html( <?php echo (count($nestedarr)); ?>);
```

for more reference **complete code with PHP**

```
    <?php

$mainarr = []; 
for($i=0; $i < count($row); $i++){
 ?>    
    <div class="news-card NewsList">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2 ">
            <div class="news-left pb-0">
                <div class="view-more"><a data-toggle="collapse" class="listSimilarNews" href="#collapse<?=$i?>" role="button" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="#collapse<?=$r?>">
                <span id ="listSimilarNews"><?php print_r(count($nestedarr)) ;  ?>
                </span><br>Articles <i class="accordionarrow icofont-rounded-down"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        </div>

        </div>

<?php
    $nestedarr=[];
    while(($j) < count($row) && ($id == (string) $row[$j]['_id'])){
      
        $i++;
        $j++; 
        array_push($nestedarr,  $row[$j]['newsSources']);
    }
         
        array_push($arr, $nestedarr);
        ?>

 <script language='javascript'>
$('#listSimilarNews').html( '<?php echo (count($nestedarr)); ?>');
 
</script>

<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: One thing is don't use `print_r` use `echo` instead.

Comment: @imvain2 Updated sir, but what about numbers which is printing 1 step below?

Comment: Wrap the PHP output in quotes: `.html('<?php echo (count($nestedarr)); ?>');`. Voting to close as a typographical issue

Comment: `$('#listSimilarNews').html( '<?php echo (count($nestedarr)); ?>');` still not working